# Undefined symbols for "__mh_execute_header"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I am building a dynamic framework. My framework linked with couple of static libraries. When It is running in simulator with sample app it works fine. But when I try to archive it with sample app I get following error from linker.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__mh_execute_header", referenced from:
```

So what is `__mh_execute_header` and what framework/library it is defined in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a linker-defined symbol. From the top of `<mach-o/ldsyms.h>`:

> This file describes the link editor defined symbols.  The semantics of
>   a link editor symbol is that it is defined by the link editor only if
>   it is referenced and it is an error for the user to define them (see
>   the man page ld(1)).  The standard UNIX link editor symbols: __end,
>   __etext and __edata are not not supported by the Apple Mach-O link editor.  These symbols are really not meaningful in a Mach-O object
>   file and the link editor symbols that are supported (described here)
>   replace them.  In the case of the standard UNIX link editor symbols
>   the program can use the symbol
>   __mh_execute_header and walk the load commands of it's program to determine the ending (or beginning) of any section or segment in the
>   program.  Note that the compiler prepends an underbar to all external
>   symbol names coded in a high level language.  Thus in 'C' names are
>   coded without an underbar and symbol names in the symbol table have an
>   underbar.  There are two cpp macros for each link editor defined name
>   in this file.  The macro with a leading underbar is the symbol name
>   and the one without is the name as coded in 'C'.

The specific symbol `__mh_execute_header` is further descibed with (emphasis added):

> The value of the link editor defined symbol [__mh_execute_header] is the
>   address of the mach header in a Mach-O executable file type.  **It does
>   not appear in any file type other than a MH_EXECUTE file type.**  The
>   type of the symbol is absolute as the header is not part of any
>   section.

So, the linker only defines `__mh_execute_header` when linking an executable, not a library, framework, or bundle.

Assuming your framework code is not referencing `_mh_execute_header`, then the reference presumably comes from the static libraries you're using. And then only when building for arm64. That's a bad thing for those libraries to be doing, since it means they can only be used in an executable, not a framework.

You didn't include where the symbol was referenced from, but that presumably would help you identify the culprit. If those static libraries are from a third party, then you will have to go to them to get help solving it.

Answer (score -1):

You should change  the code

```
dladdr(&_mh_execute_header, &info);
```

to

```
dladdr(&_MH_EXECUTE_SYM, &info);
```

Answer (score -1):

__mh_execute_header can't run in dynamic framework

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33496265)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).